# How can I get instance of a non-under test component inside my test case

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I have a component, 'ValidateSessionComponent`which uses another component 'LoginFormComponent'. 'LoginFormComponent' emits a value which`ValidateSessionComponent`should get should then call`signin`meethod of the`UserManagementService`. I have written the following test case but I get error 'Error: StaticInjectorError[LoginFormComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginFormComponent!'

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it.

```
describe('ValidateSessionComponent tests with route parameters', () => {
  let component: ValidateSessionComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ValidateSessionComponent>;

  beforeEach(async()=>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginFormComponent, //I AM INJECTING THE LOGINFORMCOMPONENT HERE
        NavComponentComponent,
        ContentComponentComponent,
        FooterComponentComponent,
        HomepageContentComponentComponent,
        ShowErrorsComponent,
        ProgressBarComponent,
        SignupComponentComponent,
        HomepageContentComponentComponent,
        NewPracticeQuestionComponent,
        PraticeQuestionListComponent,
        QuestionDetailsComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        DialogBoxComponent,
        ValidateSessionComponent],
      imports:[ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
      providers:[
        {provide: UserManagementService, useClass: MockUserManagementService},//mock user management service
        HelperService,
        DialogBoxService,
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ValidateSessionComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //using component['activatedRoute'] instead of component.route to remove editor's error that route is private.
    /*
    this is the way to return different values from a spy based on the received argument. The route will have
    params like
    {
      username:..
      redirect-to:...
      additional-redirect-info:..
    }
     */
    spyOn(component['activatedRoute'].snapshot.paramMap,'get').and.callFake(function() {
     let param = arguments[0];
     console.log('param in fake function ',param);
     if(param==='username'){
       return 'test@test.com'
     }
      if(param==='redirect-to'){
        return '/home'
      }
      if(param==='additional-redirect-info'){
        return {somearg:'somevalue'}
      }
      console.log('returning unknown param',param);
     return param;
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should send signin request on receiving form values ',(done)=>{
    let loginComponent:LoginFormComponent = TestBed.get(LoginFormComponent);
    let userService:UserManagementService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    loginComponent.formOutputEvent.emit(new LoginFormValues('test@test.com','somepassword'));
    spyOn(userService,'signinUser');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      expect(userService.signinUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new UserSigninInfo('test@test.com','somepassword'));
      done();
    },1000);

  });
});
```

In the `spec`, if I remove `LoginFormComponent` (whose selector is `app-login-form`) then I get error `Can't bind to 'userId' since it isn't a known property of 'app-login-form'.

Comment: did you try to import `RouterTestingModule` there?

Comment: And the module in which LoginFormComponent is defined?

Comment: tried but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

to get reference of the compnent, I used Viewchild. the reference from ViewChild - [How can I get reference of child component and emit a value from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263959/how-can-i-get-reference-of-child-component-and-emit-a-value-from-child-component)

Regarding the issue I was facing, it seems the issue was multiple inclusion of `LoginFormComponent`. The HTML of the `ValidateSessionComponent` had reference of the `LoginFormComponent`.

`<app-login-form (formOutputEvent)="handleFormValues($event)" [userId]="username"></app-login-form>`

This works fine so far. Then I decided to also include pass reference of `LoginFormComponent` via DI in `ValidateSessionComponent`

`constructor(private loginForm2:LoginFormComponent,private helper:HelperService,private dialogService:DialogBoxService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router, private userManagementService:UserManagementService) { }`

This started causing the error `StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ValidateSessionComponent -> LoginFormComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ValidateSessionComponent -> LoginFormComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginFormComponent!`

To be honest, I can't figure out the reason i.e. what happens under the hood in Angular which causes this issue

Comment: this answer provides more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265549/why-do-i-get-staticinjector-error-if-i-include-a-component-both-in-html-as-well/58265605#58265605