# How can I get reference of child component and emit a value from child component

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I have a parent component `ValidateSessionComponent`which has a child component `LoginFormComponent`. In my unit test, I want to emit a value from `LoginFormComponent` but I am unable to figure out how I can do so.

The HTML of the `ValidateSessionComponent` has reference of the `LoginFormComponent`.

`<app-login-form #loginForm (formOutputEvent)="handleFormValues($event)" [userId]="username"></app-login-form>`

The LoginFormComponent looks like

```
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm:FormGroup;

  formData:LoginFormValues;
  @Input() userId;
  @Output() formOutputEvent: EventEmitter<LoginFormValues>;
  existingUser:UserSigninInfo;

..
}
```

In the test, i want to emit `formOutputEvent` by calling `formOutputEvent.emit(formData);` But I can't figure out how to access `formOutputEvent` of `LoginFormComponent` in `ValidateSessionComponent`'s spec.

```
  fit('should send signin request on receiving form values ',(done)=>{
    //let loginComponent:LoginFormComponent = TestBed.get(LoginFormComponent); //IF I UNCOMMENT THIS THEN I GET ERROR NO PROVIDER OF LOGINFORMCOMPONENT
    let userService:UserManagementService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    component.loginForm.formOutputEvent.emit(new LoginFormValues('test@test.com','somepassword'));

    spyOn(userService,'signinUser');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      expect(userService.signinUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new UserSigninInfo('test@test.com','somepassword'));
      done();
    },1000);

  });
```

I thought I could use the `ViewChild` directive `@ViewChild(loginForm) loginFormRef;` but I suppose I'll get an `ElementRef`. I can't figure out how to access the `formOutputEvent`.

Comment: I figured out that I can actually use the reference from `ViewChild` and can do ` component.loginForm.formOutputEvent.emit(new LoginFormValues('test@test.com','somepassword'));
`

Comment: Yes. And you can take this stackblitz for reference... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77wzbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts