# Why do I get StaticInjector error if I include a component both in HTML as well as inject it via DI

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a component `ValidateSessionComponent` which uses `LoginFormComponent`. I use `LoginFormComponent` in `ValidateSessionComponent` by including it in the HTML of the `ValidateSessionComponent`.

This works fine so far. Then I decided to also include reference of `LoginFormComponent` via DI in `ValidateSessionComponent`

```
constructor(private loginForm2:LoginFormComponent,private helper:HelperService,private dialogService:DialogBoxService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router, private userManagementService:UserManagementService) { }
```

This started causing the error `StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ValidateSessionComponent -> LoginFormComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ValidateSessionComponent -> LoginFormComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginFormComponent!`

Why do i start getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DI works only for providers.

Components aren't providers.

If you wish to get a reference to your child element, use a `ViewChild` instead.

```
@ViewChild(LoginFormComponent, { static: true }) loginForm: LoginFormComponent;
```